# XPath select whole XPath node

Tags: xpath

Is there a possibility to select the whole path of my XPath instead of the "last" hit?

When I have the following XML:

```
...
<TagA>
    <TagB Name="MyTagB"/>
    <TagB Name="MyOtherTagB"/>
</TagA>
...
```

When I build the following XPath, I only get the "<TagB Name="MyOtherTagB"/>", but I want to have the whole node starting at "<TagA>..."

```
//*[local-name()='TagA']/*[local-name()='TagB' and @Name='MyTagB']/following-sibling::*[local-name()='TagB' and @Name='MyOtherTagB']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `//*[local-name()='TagA']`.

Comment: That was my thought too, but I guess they wouldn't be asking the question if it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need only the TagA if both TagB's are present. If yes try this:

```
//*[local-name()='TagA'][
 *[local-name()='TagB' and @Name='MyTagB'] 
  and 
 *[local-name()='TagB' and @Name='MyOtherTagB']
]
```